# Difference Output between Debug and Release version in ASP Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, filestream

I've written following code in my application

```
fs = new FileStream(OutputFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8, 512))
{
  //add some text to sb
  writer.Write(sb.ToString());
  writer.Close();
}
finally
{
  if (fs != null)
  {
     fs.Close();
     fs.Dispose();
  }
```

Now when I use application and click on output button, my output file has html code of using page after desired output. but when I use debug tool to find what is wrong with my code, every thing is perfect! even my output file!

Edit: Here is my Output

Debug Version(right output)

```
 //Exact text that I added to sb above
```

Release Version(wrong output)

```
//Exact text that I added to sb above 
<!DOCTYPE html ....//All html Code of using page that I download output file from it
```

Excuse me for grammar mistakes, English is not my native language.

Comment: Can you show the **actual** output from the Debug and Release so we can compare the two?

Comment: _You should also use `using` with `fs = new FileStream` to avoid the explicit `Close` and `Dispose`. Like you did with `writer`._

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for your reply.  I've edited question, does it help now?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] as right now, with the code in the question, the file shouldn't contain anything at all. Please show how you're filling the string builder with content. It would also not compile since there is a finally-block without a matching try block.

Comment: Also, **be specific**, you say "output file", do you mean the file you wrote the string builder content into? Do you mean a file the user downloaded from your page? If so then post the download code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want something along these lines:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Add("Some text");

// Clear anything the page has begun to buffer. We don't want that.
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();


// Write something to the Response.OutputStream here
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.CharSet = "utf-8";
Response.OutputStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));

// Send to the client immediately.
Response.Flush();
// Prevent any more being added by ASP.Net
Response.SuppressContent = true;
```